# Using logisimayml module with the Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, yaml

I am using the logisimayml 1.5 module with my Play app to produce yml from the contents in my live database.  The module traverses the JPA classes to identify children to determine what gets written out into the yml.

So if I had two simple JPA classes like this:

```
public class Parent extends Model {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", targetEntity = Child.class)
    public List<Child> children;

    ...
}

public class Child extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    public Parent parent;

    ...
}
```

When I run logisimayml, it will produce a data.yml file that looks like this:

```
Parent(Parent_1):
 name: Bill
 children:
 - Child_1

Parent(Parent_2):
 name: Bill

Child(Child_3):
 name: Jill

Child(Child_1):
 name: Jill
 parent: Parent_1
```

Now the yml above does represent what the JPA classes represent however I would like to use the data.yml file for loading into my app using:

```
Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");
```

This doesn't quite work because Bill is first and it wants to find the child Jill.  Jill however has not yet been declared and therefore it falls over.  This stems from the fact that I have used both @OneToMany in Parent and @ManyToOne in Child meaning it is bi-directional.  I could remove the @OneToMany but I still want it in there for my code.  Does anyone know what I could do to keep the JPA classes as they are but have the yml render without an infinite loop between the Parent and Child?

**Update:** Here the exception I see when I start up my Play app pointing to the data.yml created by logisimayml:

```
RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture data.yml: No previous reference found for object of type sites with key User_25
```

The first object in the data.yml references User_25 as a child.  The declaration of User_25 is much further down in my data.yml.  As Luffy mentioned below, my simple Parent-Child example does not actually cause the exception to occur.  My actual project has quite a large database so it is hard to replicate in a simple example here, though I thought it had something to do with the bi-directional annotations but I guess not after all.  I also updated the data.yml for my example above.  I actually do what Luffy did and created an actual project with the simple Parent-Child example and after running the module, it actually produced something slightly different than my hand crafted yml.  Using that yml in the Fixtures.loadModels(..) call actually works though so it doesn't really reflect the issue exactly as I see it in production so I will have to get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "fetch = FetchType.LAZY" in ManyToOne annotation. This may help to fix your issue.

```
@ManyToOne(name = "parent_id", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: In my actual code I have the fetch type of lazy.  I just didn't include it in my example in the OP.

Comment: It's weird i just test your senario in new play project. Its loading that simple example yml at boostrap succesfully. I checked db both bill and jill there. I am using play 1.2.4. And i create yml file manually. Used postgresql for testing.

Comment: you're right. the simple example I put in the OP actually works. My large app with the large yml still doesn't work.  I will have to get back with a example that actually replicates the problem I am seeing.  Thanks for finding that issue in my super simple example!

Comment: I have updated my OP with a more accurate data.yml produced by the logisimayml module as well as the exception I see in my production play app (which I can't quite re-produce yet using my simple Parent-Child example)

Comment: Which play version are you using ? I asked because there was a bug  one of the previous releases about loading big yml files.

Comment: Play 1.2.4 and logisimayml 1.5.

Comment: Checkout this link . https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/ETB2c2oYeM0 Same problem. Probably this is not solved yet.

Comment: I'm surprised that the data.yml in my OP works then since Bill references Jill who doesn't exist until later in the yml. thanks for the link.